# Addition Theorem for Sequence Limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If $lim(a_n-b_n)$ exists and it's equal to $0$, and $lim (b_n)$ also exists, can I conclude that $lim(a_n) $exists and $lim(a_n) = lim(b_n)$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. $a_n=b_n+(a_n-b_n)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh, thank you so much!!!